# Kubernetes (in Docker for Windows) Volume Configuration for Postgres

Tags: kubernetes, docker-volume

I have a tomcat + postgres application that I test with docker-compose.  I am trying to package the application in a kubernetes config file.

For now, I am running kubernetes (and kubectl) using my Docker Desktop for Windows installation.  Eventually, I want to deploy to other environments.

I am currently trying to replicate some of the volume functionality in docker-compose within the following config file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pg-pod
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: "pgdata-vol"
    #emptyDir: {}
    hostPath:
      path: /c/temp/vols/pgdata
  containers:
  - image: postgres
    name: db
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5432
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/pgdata"
      name: "pgdata-vol"
    env:
    - name: PGDATA
      value: /pgdata
```

When postgres launches, I get see the following error.

```
fixing permissions on existing directory /pgdata ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
2019-07-26 20:43:41.844 UTC [78] FATAL:  data directory "/pgdata" has wrong ownership
2019-07-26 20:43:41.844 UTC [78] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/pgdata"
running bootstrap script ...
```

I presume that I either need to provide some additional parameters to my volume definition or I need to try a different type of volume config (**local** vs **hostPath**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a partial solution to this issue.

Interestingly, if I assign a linux-style path as my host-path (on Windows), then my pgdata-vol persists until Docker Desktop is restarted.

Instead of mounting to a real windows location

```
  volumes:
  - name: "pgdata-vol"
    hostPath:
      path: /c/temp/vols/pgdata
```

I use a "linux" location as my Windows hostPath

```
  volumes:
  - name: "pgdata-vol"
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/vols/pgdata
```

Curiously, I cannot actually find this path from Windows.  I presume this /tmp is local to my Docker Desktop instance.

This solution does not offer true persistence, but it has helped me to work around a roadblock that was impacting testing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Docker image on Windows. Right now it is not possible to correctly mount Windows directories as volumes. You may however try to workaround it by using a persistent Docker volume. For example:

```
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=<user>
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<pass>
      - POSTGRES_DB=<db_name>
    ports:
      - <ports>
    volumes:
      - pgdata:<path>
    networks:
    - <network>

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

More Information:

- [data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/435)
- [postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership](https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963)
- [postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount](https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-get-postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount-two-issues/12456)

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks.  When I run my system with docker-compose, I create a volume as you have described above.  I wish I knew of a way to mount a volume created as you describe to kubernetes.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)?

Comment: I had found that page, but I am unclear how to implement the options in my example.  Ideally, I would simply like to replicate the type of volume that docker-compose creates (and persists).

Comment: I see your point. I think it would be best if you ask this in a separate question. Would be easier and more transparent for all folks interested.

Comment: I have created a new question.  Thank you for the suggestion.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378980/replicate-docker-compose-volume-behavior-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using WSL? My setup for windows is WSL + Ubuntu + Docker for windows and I can mount volumes normally.

I've followed that tutorial to configure all my environment:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly