# Replicate docker-compose volume behavior in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am migrating a docker-compose file for a tomcat + postgres application to kubernetes.  My test environment is Dockers for Windows with Kubernetes enabled.

If I use an emptyDir volume for postgres, I am able to test my application successfully, but I am unable to persist postgres data.

```
      volumes:
      - name: "pgdata-vol"
        emptyDir: {}
```

On MacOS, I am able to persist postgres data using a hostPath volume.

```
  volumes:
  - name: "pgdata-vol"
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/vols/pgdata
```

Unfortunately, if I try the same solution on Windows, I encounter a permission error.  This was discussed in a previous question. See  [Kubernetes (in Docker for Windows) Volume Configuration for Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227990/kubernetes-in-docker-for-windows-volume-configuration-for-postgres).

I do not need to access my volumes through the host file system.  I simply want my volume to persist from one run to the next.  I am able to achieve this behavior when running `docker-compose ... up` and `docker-compose ... down` using the following volume definition.

```
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Volume reference

```
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/pgdata
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/pgdata
```

Is there a good name to use to describe this type of volume?  Is there a way to translate this type of volume into kubernetes?

Answer (score 2):

Empty dir is indeed for temporary data. 
If you need persistent data you have the choice between using a host path like in Docker, but if you have multiple nodes an a pod is scheduled for a different node the data will be missing.

A better solution is therefore to use a persistent volume. This must be provided by your infrastructure and is therefore specific to your environment.

See for details: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/

For the permission problem on Docker for Windows you might want to consider to use minikube instead.